# C++ Do-while loop stopping

Tags: c++, do-while

I got an assignment where we make a cmd prompt show up and display a flashcard game for multiplication. After inputting a correct answer a prompt shows up and asks the user to go "Again? Y/N." after the second input answer the prompt to ask the user doesn't show up and it's stuck on a "congratulations" message. This happens when I write in code to randomly generate two numbers for the game twice. one outside the  while loop, and one inside while loop. If I leave one out the 2nd code for the random numbers it will run fine but will only display the same numbers over again. what I'm asking is how do I fix it so that it won't get stuck after the second answer input?

sample code below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, ans, guess, count = 0;
    char choice;

    num1 = rand() % 12 + 1;  
    num2 = rand() % 12 + 1;
    //first number generator.
    ans = num1 * num2;

    do
    {
        {
            cout << num1 << " X " << num2 << " = ";
            cin >> guess;
            cout << "Wow~! Congratulations~! ";
            count++;

            num1 = rand() % 12 + 1;
            num2 = rand() % 12 + 1;
            //second number generator.

        } while (guess != ans);


        cout << "\nAgain? Y/N: ";
        cin >> choice;

    } while ((choice == 'y') || (choice == 'Y'));
    //after two turns the loop stops. Can't make a choice.

    cout << " Thanks for playing! Number of tries:" << count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing the `do` verb for the `while (guess != ans)` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be found here:

```
do
{
    {
        cout << num1 << " X " << num2 << " = ";
        cin >> guess;
```

As you can see, the second scope has no `do` statement. As a result it is only a codeblock.

You can solve it by writing a `do` statement for the second code block.

Because the `do` is not present in the second bracket (`{`), the `while` is interpreted as a `while` loop:

```
while (guess != ans);
```

or

```
while (guess != ans) {
}
```

this thus keeps looping until `guess` is not equal to `ans`. But since in the loop does not modify any of the two variables, the loop will keep iterating.

---

**Other errors**: note that the program is still incorrect, since it will claim you have answered the question, regardless of the answer. You can fix it by implementing this as follows:

```
int main()
{
    int num1, num2, ans, guess, count = 0;
    char choice;

    do {

       num1 = rand() % 12 + 1;
       num2 = rand() % 12 + 1;
       ans = num1 * num2;

       do {
            cout << num1 << " X " << num2 << " = ";
            cin >> guess;
            if(guess == ans) {
                cout << "Wow~! Congratulations~! ";
            } else {
                cout << "No, wrong!\n";
            }
            count++;

        } while (guess != ans);


        cout << "\nAgain? Y/N: ";
        cin >> choice;

    } while ((choice == 'y') || (choice == 'Y'));
    //after two turns the loop stops. Can't make a choice.

    cout << " Thanks for playing! Number of tries:" << count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh woah, I totally forgot about if and else statements. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'd guess the problem is because your loops aren't quite what you think they are.

```
do
{
```

The code above has started a `do` loop.

```
    {
```

I suspect you intended to start another (nested) `do` loop here--but you left off the `do`, so it's just a block that gets entered, executed, and exited. Useless and pointless in this case.

```
        cout << num1 << " X " << num2 << " = ";
        cin >> guess;
        cout << "Wow~! Congratulations~! ";
        count++;

        num1 = rand() % 12 + 1;
        num2 = rand() % 12 + 1;
        //second number generator.

    } while (guess != ans);
```

You've formatted this as if the `while` were closing the nested `do` loop--but since you didn't actually create a nested `do` loop, this is just a `while` loop with an empty body. Its meaning would be more apparent with a little re-formatting:

```
    // second number generator
}

while (guess != ans)
    /* do nothing */
    ;
```

Comment: Although this solves the problem, the program is (still) semantically incorrect since it says that every answer is correct.

Comment: Oh, I see now. thank you sharing your knowldge with me!